# Problem building a Java Rules app in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, drools, runtime-error

I'm trying to build a simple Drools project in Eclipse, but when I try to test it, a runtime exception is thrown with the message, "The Eclipse JDT Core jar is not in the classpath."

Any ideas where I might find this jar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://affy.blogspot.com/2008/07/jboss-rules-classpath-error-eclipse-jdt.html

If it's not that, please provide some more info on your problem...